# Javascript increment variable to update table cells onclick

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, onclick

I have a page where the user inputs a color and I call the onClick method to change the color of the individual cells of the table. However, when I click any cell, only the last cell (cell3 in this case) will change color. What am I doing wrong?

I get the error:

> Message: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object
>       Line: 24
>       Char: 4
>       Code: 0

My code is:

```
    <html>

    <body>
    <input type='text' id='userInput' value='yellow' />

    <table border="1"> 
        <tr>
            <td id="1">cell1
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="2">cell2
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="3">cell3
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
        document.getElementById(i).onclick = function(){
        var newColor = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
            document.getElementById(i).style.backgroundColor = newColor;
        }
    }
    </script> 
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your HTML to this:  An ID must start with an an alpha character.  It is not valid to start with a number.

```
<table border="1"> 
    <tr>
        <td id="td1">cell1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="td2">cell2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="td3">cell3
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

This is a very common Javascript issue: All the code shares the value of `i` which is `3` at the end of the loop.  You can solve it by using another helper function like this:

```
function changeIt(i) {
  // This inner function now has its own private copy of 'i'
  return function() {
    var newColor = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
      document.getElementById("td" + i).style.backgroundColor = newColor;
  }
}

for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
    document.getElementById(i).onclick = changeIt(i);
}
```

It can also be written using an anonymous function, but those are harder to read.

Comment: I was about to upvote, but your code does not solve the problem, you must replace `document.getElementById(i).onclick = function() { changeIt(i); }` with `document.getElementById(i).onclick = changeIt(i);`

Comment: Good point with the variable scope and alpha character id's. I'd prefer just using `this`, though.

Comment: @StuartWakefield -- Yeah, I did slightly screw that up.  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @EricLennartsson -- `this` would be a better choice, but then we'd have lost the chance to head off future questions.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your for loop is wrong. Try:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
   //code
}
```

Second, instead of retrieving the element each time in your loop, you could use `this`:

```
this.style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
```

Comment: Updated to use the `this` keyword, which should make your code work. Also, like Jeremy pointed out, you shouldn't start an element id with a number.

Answer (score 1):

Jeremy's answer is close but there is still a problem in that changeIt is not being called until the element is clicked, by which time the value of i is still three. Using Jeremy's update to the HTML the correct script can be written as...

```
function createChangeColorHandler(n) {
  return function() {
    var newColor = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    document.getElementById("td" + n).style.backgroundColor = newColor;
  }
}

for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  // We pass i to the function createChangeColorHandler by value
  // at the time of this pass of the loop rather than referencing 
  // the variable directly after the loop has finished
  document.getElementById(i).onclick = createChangeColorHandler(i);
}
```

As an anonymous function...

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  // We pass i to the function createChangeColorHandler by value
  // at the time of this pass of the loop rather than referencing 
  // the variable directly after the loop has finished
  document.getElementById(i).onclick = (function(n) {
    return function() {
      var newColor = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
      document.getElementById("td" + n).style.backgroundColor = newColor;
    }
  })(i);
}
```

**EDIT** Jeremy's answer is now correct